# Need To Stop Folder's Homepage Following Root's Redirect

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I set my site up so that the root domain (flippinghousesforrookies.com) redirects to another site, but now the folders (flippinghousesforrookies.com/blog for example) I set up are also redirecting to the other site instead of their own index.php.

Any inside pages of the folders (flippinghousesforrookies.com/blog/contact for example) work fine, but not the homepage of each folder.

Not that I think it matters, but the site is set up as an add-on domain in it's hosting and each folder has a Wordpress install.

Here's the root's .htaccess:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on

#RewriteOptions inherit

# To set your custom php.ini, add the following line to this file:
# suphp_configpath /home/yourusername/path/to/php.ini
# php_value mbstring.func_overload 4 # Required for PWSB support. Please do not uncomment this line.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^flippinghousesforrookies\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.flippinghousesforrookies\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/flippinghousesforrookies\.mykajabi\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

And here is one of the folder's .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you used in your root .htaccess file is too long for the purpose you are trying to do.

You can do this in two ways.

a) 
In the root .htaccess file put this code instead of the one you were entering:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://flippinghousesforrookies.mykajabi.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code checks if there is /blog in the URL. If it is, then this rewrite rule will **not** be met and therefore it will not redirect the visitor to the new page. If there is nothing behind the url (so no subfolders) then the visitor will be redirected to the new page.

b) You can use only this part of the code. It redirects only the root folder to the new domain and it leaves all subfolders as they are.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://example2.com/
```

P.S. - Both work, but I  added both solutions so you can adapt it to your own taste.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the first option and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad I could help you, @Emma! If this answer suited your needs you can mark it as the best answer on the left side of it, under the voting buttons.

Comment: I know this is months later, but I went to go redirect the site one more time and ran into the same exact problem. Thankfully I remembered this response. So I just wanted to say a double thank you for saving my ass twice!

Comment: @Emma I'm glad I could be of assistance :)